# Unity3d - Turret stops shooting when player is stationary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing a 2D top down game and I have a problem with my Turret AI. Everything works perfectly except, when the player is stationary, the turret stops shooting. The bulletTimer stops increasing when player stops, instead of increasing over time. I'm guessing it has something to do with Time.deltaTime and frame refreshing but couldn't find a workaround. Do I need to write an attack function with IEnumerator and waitforseconds? It feels like it's a simple problem yet I'm unable to solve it. Thanks for the help. Here is my code :

TurretAI code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretAI : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
     public float FireRate;
     public float bulletSpeed;
     public float bulletTimer;

     public GameObject Gun;
     public GameObject bullet;
     public Transform target;


     public void Attack()
     {    
         bulletTimer += Time.deltaTime;

         if (bulletTimer >= FireRate) 
         {
             Vector2 direction = target.transform.position - transform.position;
             direction.Normalize ();

             GameObject bulletClone;
             bulletClone = Instantiate (bullet, Gun.transform.position, Gun.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
             bulletClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = direction * bulletSpeed;

             bulletTimer = 0;
         }
     }
 }
```

And this is the Turret Trigger code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretTrigger : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public TurretAI turretAI;

    void Awake()
    { 
        turretAI = gameObject.GetComponentInParent<TurretAI> (); 
    }

     void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D Trigger)
     {
         if (Trigger.CompareTag ("Player")) 
         {
             turretAI.Attack ();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: do you change `Time.timeScale` at any point? If you do then changing your `Time.deltaTime` to `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` might help.

Comment: I haven't changed timescale at all. I can actually record a video of what's happening if it might help.

Comment: Is OnTriggerStay2D calling on every frame? Put a Debug.Log there and check if it's colliding. The following code seems ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your player's `rigidBody2D` is falling asleep when it's not moving (this is the engine optimizing performance, nothing that you have done). When `rigidBody`s sleep, the `OnTriggerStay2D` will stop detecting them. Calling `rigidBody2D.WakeUp()` on your player's `rigidBody2D` will force the `rigidBody` to wake up and be detected by the trigger box.

I can't find a more efficient way of making sure that the `rigidBody` stays awake just now. Try this to see if it what is causing your problem and then, if it is, try to find a more efficient way of stooping the `ridgidBody` sleeping!

Edit: Gunnar B has pointed out that this can be set in the inspector. Go to  your player's RigidBody` component and set 'Sleeping Mode' to 'Never Sleep'.

Comment: Was about to write the same. I think, you can set the sleeping mode in the rigidbody component though. (Never sleep should be an option.)

Comment: I was sure that it was something as simple as that. Thank you very much. Problem solved =)